# Azure Search, One or more errors occurred. Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

It is a Cloud Service in Azure working against the Azure Search service.
It all works fine but sometimes we get the following exception,

> An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to connect to the
>   remote server

Is there a way to trace the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

After discussing with the support of Azure, they claim it was an update they doing every now and then.

Only another replica for the service can make 100% accessibility.